# How can I access a file in a completely different directory based on absolute path (Python)

Tags: python, absolute-path

```py
import os
test = os.path.exists("c:/conf.txt")
if test == False:
    with open("c:/conf.txt", "w") as Inc:
        Inc.write("0")
        Inc.close()
        quit()
if test == True:
    f = open("c:/conf.txt", 'r')
    b = int(f.readline())
    b +=1
    with open("c:/conf.txt", 'w') as writeinc:
        writeinc.write(str(b))
        writeinc.close()
```

using `open(c:/conf.txt)` doesn't work (also tried c:\.)

I get the following error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'c:/conf.txt'
```

Is there a way to access a different directory using `open()` according to absolute path rather than relative?

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Do you get an error message?  If so, please include the full error message in your post.

Comment: You only seem to be accessing one file which you are creating in the  C: directory if it does not already exist. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Padraic

It doesn't matter what I'm trying to do, but how I can even do it.

Comment: Try `"c:\\conf.txt"` or `r"c:\conf.txt"`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Neither of those work, they both raise the IOError mentioned above.

Comment: It works fine for me (using forward slashes).

Comment: @BrenBarn None of the methods shown work for me. I've used:

"c:\\conf.txt"

r"c:\conf.txt"

"c:/conf.txt"

"c://conf.txt"

"c:\conf.txt"

All of these return the IOError.

Comment: @Peaser: What is your Python version and platform?

Comment: @BrenBarn Version 2.7 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Try creating `conf.txt` manually in the same folder as your app and opening it with an absolute path `c:\\path\\to\\my\\app\\conf.txt` to rule out a permission error.

Comment: @MartinKonecny I would, however that would ruin the whole purpose of my script. It is meant to create a file if it doesn't exist, and work from there.

Comment: Which line is the error on? After the second `if` statement, you try to open the file twice.

Comment: @Peaser Yes, this is for debugging purposes only.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths It is on line 4 (with open..) and The first open is a read, second is a write

Comment: I think the OP would get a permission denied error if it  was to do  with  write permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you don't have permission to write to the root path of your drive. In Windows 7 and 8, you cannot create files in the root directory:

> In Windows 7 or 8 (may be Vista), users (even administrators) are not
>   allowed to create files in the C drive root directory, otherwise, an
>   error message like “A required privilege is not held by the client” or
>   “access is denied” will be prompted.

[Source](http://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/cant-create-file-in-the-c-drive-root-directory-windows-8/)

The article goes on how to modify the registry if you want to get around this restriction.

> 1. Press keys “Windows Key + R”, type regedit
> 2. Locate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA
> 3. Update the EnableLUA value to 0 (turn if off)
> 4. Restart Windows.

Comment: Interesting.  If I try to write to a directory where I don't have permission, I get a "permission denied" error, not the "invalid filename" error.